# How to merge 2 result sets using RedShift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

We charge different people, different prices for the same product.
I have a pricing table in a RedShift DB set up like this.
A userId of -1 is the default pricing.

```
------- pricing_table -------
id   name         userId  price
1    product a    -1      1.00
2    product b    -1      1.25
3    product c    -1      1.50
4    product a    47      0.50
5    product c    47      0.75
```

I would like to get a complete price list for a single user in 1 query.
For instance if I wanted to get a price list for user 47, I would expect the result to be

```
------- results for user 47 -------
id   name         userId  price
4    product a    47      0.50
2    product b    -1      1.25
5    product c    47      0.75
```

If I wanted to get a price list for user 111 (who had no entries in the pricing table), I would expect this result

```
------- results for user 111 -------
id   name         userId  price
1    product a    -1      1.00
2    product b    -1      1.25
3    product c    -1      1.50
```

My Question is; is there a single query I can execute on a RedShift DB, that takes only a userId, and produces the result sets, required for both scenarios, and what would that query look like?

Using CASE WHEN on every single product would not be a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `or` with a correlated subquery:

```
select name, user_id, price
from t
where user_id = 111 or
      (user_id = -1 and
       not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.name = t.name and t2.user_id = 47);
```

Another method uses `row_number():

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by user_id desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where user_id in (-1, 47)
    ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note that neither of these redefine the first column.  That doesn't seem useful, but you can use `row_number()` if you really want a sequential number in the result set.

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank You